# Update elements of a list

Tags: python, list, updating

Why aren't the elements updated within the for-loop? This gets me

```
met_dir = r'D:\09052012\run\fout'
out_dir = r'D:\inpassingstest\test_cmd'

for c_dir in [met_dir,out_dir]:
    if c_dir[-1:] != '\\':
       c_dir += '\\'
       print c_dir
print met_dir

>>>D:\09052012\run\fout\
>>>D:\inpassingstest\test_cmd\
>>>D:\09052012\run\fout
```

Same happens when I use a index to address the elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable objects, that is, you cannot change it, instead making new strings. This means that when you append to the string, the original remains unchanged. The easy solution to this is a list comprehension, to make a new list of the new strings:

```
>>> [c_dir + "\\" if not c_dir.endswith("\\") else c_dir for c_dir in (met_dir, out_dir)]
['D:\\09052012\\run\\fout\\', 'D:\\inpassingstest\\test_cmd\\']
```

Which one can easily unpack back into the values:

```
met_dir, out_dir = [...]
```

Note my use of `str.endswith()` which is a nice way of doing the check.

Comment: Yeah, the `str.endswith()` is a good choice here. Hadn't thought about that.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable in Python. `c_dir += '\\'` creates a new string with `\\` appended, but doesn't replace the original.

Comment: But using an index should do the trick, right? But it doesn't.

Comment: @larsvegas -- using an index doesn't work.  (strings don't support assignment to their slices because strings are *immutable*) -- In other words, when you make a string, you can't change it (period).  All you can hope to do is make a new string from the data in the old one.

Comment: @larsvegas No, using the index changes nothing. You can only change the contents of the temporary list you're iterating over, but not the original strings you stored in `met_dir` and `out_dir`. The problem is that you're never updating those variables, and you simply can't change the objects they point to in-place.

Comment: @mgilson, I know. I meant accessing the element by index like `for i in xrange(len(..))`. But the comment of @millimoose clarified that.

Comment: @larsvegas As a note, accessing by index is always the wrong course of action in Python. It's not how Python is designed and it's never needed.

Comment: @larsvegas `for i in xrange(len(...))` is a clunky way of doing that anyway. `for i, val in enumerate(...)` is the more Pythonic idiom.

Comment: @millimoose, It was just an example.

Answer (score 2):

`strings` in Python are immutable, you cannot change their contents like that. What happens is that in this line:

```
c_dir += '\\'
```

the local variable `c_dir` is replaced with a new string (with `\\` appended). This new string is lost when you leave the loop iteration.